# datatable add class a td render

Tags: javascript, datatables

How Can I add a class in this render where I ask if the office is enable or disable, if this disable  should add this class `table-active`. I was searching for some similar question but none worked.

```
var table = $('#tbl_1').DataTable({
            "order": [
                [1, "asc"]
            ],
            "destroy": true,
            "ajax": {
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "JSON/Office.php"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 15,
            "columns": [ {
                "data": "Office",
                "width": "20%"
            },  {
                "data": "Status",
                "searchable": false,
                "sortable": false,
                "aling": "center",
                "render": function(data, type, row) {
                    var Status = row["Status"];
                    if (Status == 'FALSE') {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success active" onclick="enable_item(this)"title="Active">Active</button>';
                    } else {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger disable" onclick="disable_item(this)" title="Disable"> Disable</button>';
                    }
                }
            }],
            "dom": '<"dt-buttons"Bf><"clear">lirtp',
            "paging": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Excel'
            }]
        });
```

One of the answer I found was this `$(row).addClass("table-active");` but still not working :(. I hope I explain well greetings

Comment: Do you want to assign some class to entire row or some particular cell?

Comment: @ygorbunkov the row

Comment: Than, I believe, provided answer is supposed to fulfill your requirement? Doesn't it?

Comment: Doesnt work cause Im using `render`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correct and you want to add a class to the `<tr>` element you can use the `createdRow` hook - https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow.

```
$('#tbl_1').dataTable({
  "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    if ( data["Status"] == false ) {
      $(row).addClass( 'table-active' );
    }
  }
});
```